# Perl unite 2 regexps into 1

Tags: regex, perl

A valid string should either consist of Cyrillic characters or Latin characters only.

I created a working solution with 2 regexps. But when I try to unite them into 1, it fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use v5.14;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

my @data = (
    # rus - ok
    "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯ",
    # space
    "а бвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯ",
    # rus - latin
    "аtбвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯ",
    # digit
    "аб2вгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьыъэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЫЪЭЮЯ",
    # latin - ok
    "abcdefghejklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHEJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    # space
    "a bcdefghejklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHEJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    # underscore
    "a_bcdefghejklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHEJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    # digit
    "a2bcdefghejklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHEJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
);

foreach(@data) {
    if ($_ =~ /^[а-яё]+$/i or $_ =~ /^[a-z]+$/i) {
        print "ok\n";
    }
    else {
        print "bad\n";
    }
}

print "-------\n";
foreach(@data) {
    if ($_ =~ /^(:?[а-яё]+)|(:?[a-z]+)$/i) {
        print "ok\n";
    }
    else {
        print "bad\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ok
bad
bad
bad
ok
bad
bad
bad
-------
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
```

For some reason the second regexp always succeeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your regex,

- `:?` - matches an optional `:` while you wanted to define a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970), `(?:...)`
- `^(?:a+)|(?:b+)$` - matches either `a`s at the start of the string OR `b`s at the end of the string.

You should use

```perl
/^(?:[а-яё]+|[a-z]+)$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qnUAKn/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `[а-яё]+` - one or more Russian letters
  - `|` - or
  - `[a-z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

**NOTE**: Starting from Perl 5.22, you may use the [`n` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#n) to make capturing groups behave as non-capturing, `/^([а-яё]+|[a-z]+)$/ni`. So, there could be no risk of mixing `?:` and `:?`.

Check the core version with `use v5.22.0;` in this case.